# FolderBrowserDialog в WPF (.NET 5)

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-5

Мне необходимо выбирать путь до директории при помощи FolderBrowserDialog, но чтобы его использовать необходимо обратиться к пространству имен System.Windows.Forms, в котором FolderBrowserDialog отсутствует. Я поискал в COM библиотеках и нашел какую-то зависимость System_Windows_Forms, но это не решило мою проблему, полагаю, эта библиотека была не совместима с моим проектом (у меня .NET 5). Так же, в зависимостях я не нашел System.Windows.Forms. Есть ли какие-нибудь замены FolderBrowserDialog в WPF?

Comment: Непонятно почему ms не озаботилось им, поэтому приходится использовать [велосипедостроение](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/438). Ну а вообще для System.Windows.Forms нужно в *.csproj указать `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот код в файле `*.csproj` позволил мне обращаться к пространству имен `System.Windows.Forms`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   //тут еще теги
   <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
</PropertyGroup>
```

---

Так же, вопрос решает NuGet пакет: `Install-Package Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf` а в C# классе я написал:

```
VistaFolderBrowserDialog dialog = new VistaFolderBrowserDialog();
dialog.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: А зачем вам тогда UseWindowsForms, если вы взяли один из WPF вариантов?

Comment: Вы уверены, что библиотеки с диалогами надостаточно и нужно сразу и формы и библиотеку прикручивать одновременно?

Comment: Вы правы, я это написал для тех, у кого будет такая же проблема (не будет пространства имен System.Windows.Forms), а сам я использовал второй вариант

Comment: @AlAvenger немного изменил формулировку в ответе, чтобы не сбивать людей с толку.

Comment: Кстати, кое-какие диалоги есть в пространстве имен `Microsoft.Win32` - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32?view=windowsdesktop-5.0

Answer (score 3):

К сожалению, в WPF есть лишь встроенный [диалог выбора файла](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog?view=windowsdesktop-5.0), но не каталога, хотя запрос на включение такого диалога [есть](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/438).

Если вы не хотите тащить за собой Winforms, обычно используют неофициальный nuget-пакет WindowsApiCodePack (их много, но официального на данный момент нету). Например, можно взять [вот этот](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft-WindowsAPICodePack-Shell/), для чего добавьте в ваш .csproj следующую строку:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft-WindowsAPICodePack-Shell" Version="1.1.4" />
```

(возможно, версия на тот момент, когда вы читаете ответ, будет поновее).

После этого ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```cs
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs;

...

CommonOpenFileDialog ofd = new() { IsFolderPicker = true };
ofd.ShowDialog();
```

Это даст такой диалог:

[image: а ещё добавим ножек — получился диаложек]