# .Net 6 как открыть окно windows из консоли

Tags: c#, .net

мне нужно из консоли запустить OpenFileDialog, для выбора файлов, но столкнулся с такой проблемой, что на .Net 6 не подключается и не устанавливается библиотека System.Windows.Forms;
подскажите пожалуйста, что делать? может есть альтернатива?

Comment: опечатка `syste` вместо `system`?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1337132/folderbrowserdialog-%d0%b2-wpf-net-5 (работает так же для .NET 6)

Comment: Спасибо, решилась редактированием *.csproj